# How to compute expected value of a normal distribution over [0, + infinity) interval

Tags: probability

Let $\xi \in N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, how to compute expectation of $\xi$ over $[0, +\infty]$ interval?
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}dx$$

Comment: If you know that $$\int_0^\infty  e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$ then this should be pretty easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Change variables to $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$.  The result will involve the standard normal CDF.